# WFFM form hidden state on rendering

Tags: wffm, mvc-forms

I am working on WFFM form where I am dynamically rendering WFFM form on web page which is working perfectly fine on my local machine by using below code

```
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{F2CCA16D-7524-4E99-8EE0-78FF6394A3B3}", new { Datasource = "<id of the form item>" , UniqueId = "<unique id of the form rendering>"})
```

But when I deployed it on our server, WFFM form and its fields are rendering propely as I can identify it from View Source my webpage on browser. But interestingly WFFM form and its fields are rendering as hidden.

I tried multiple options like

- Disabling project CSS and javascripts
- Republishing items
- Try it on different server

but unable to resolve it.

I am using Web Forms For Marketers 8.1 rev. 151217.

Do anybody face the similar situation of WFFM form hidden state while rendering?

Comment: List the "multiple options" you've tried, please. We also need to know more about your versions and how you are "dynamically rendering" the WFFM form. Please see: http://meta.sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/136/what-makes-a-good-post

Comment: Is there anything outside of WFFM hiding that div. Something in the CSS that is different?

Comment: @RReilley .. I cross-checked it and this is not the case.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I updated question with more details.

Comment: May i know what is the use case for this approach?

Answer (score 2):

I am able to resolve this by

- Reinstalling WFFM CM package on server
- Republishing all WFFM related items
- Clear the Sitecore Cache